# Logging in Python. Can someone explain?

Tags: python, logging

This is directly from the Python 2.7.13 documentation.

It says:

```
import logging
logging.warning('Watch out!') # will print a message to the console
logging.info('I told you so') # will not print anything.
```

If you type these lines into a script and run it, you will see:
WARNING:root:Watch out!.

The INFO message doesn't appear because the default level is WARNING

I don't really understand why the INFO message does not appear. What does it mean that the default level is WARNING?

Comment: before that add `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)` now you should see the print ... this allows you to specify your verbosity level via commandline arguments (ie in general you dont want to see debug or info prints, but under some conditions you might wish to see that info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default log level is the *minimum* level that logs will appear in your terminal.

That is to say, if your default log level was WARNING, at *minimum* you would see logs at level WARNING.  You'd also likely see ERROR and CRITICAL messages, too.

If you lowered your log level, you would be able to see the other messages.  It's usually not done too often since logs get more verbose and more noisy, but useful if you need to do some deep debugging.